# Jquery Dialog Close not worked correctly

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog

> hello guys :    i'm trying to make popup using Jquery inside Razor Mvc
>   4 , the popup done correctly but the problem when i press on close "x"
>   and press again to let popup appears again jquery redirect to new page
>   that contains the content of the dialog  when im refresh the page and
>   let dialog apears again worked

```
$("#dialog-edit").dialog({
         title: 'Card Types',
         autoOpen: false,
         resizable: false,
         dialogClass: 'CreateClass',
         closeOnEscape: false,
         width: 400,
         show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
         modal: true,
         draggable: false,
         open: function (event, ui) {
             $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
             $(this).load(url);
         }
     });

  $("#lnkCreate").live("click", function (e) {
         //e.preventDefault(); //use this or return false
        // 
         url = $(this).attr('href');
         $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');

         return false;
     });
```

Comment: Does the console throw any js-errors on the second click?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Comment: Is it possible that the content you are loading have additional Javascript inside? Sometimes this can make trouble e.g. if the target url loads a complete html header (inclusive libraries) again.

Comment: thanks a lot the html code that i loaded inside dialog contains jquery libraries when i comment it its works

Answer (score 0):

the answer is 
the partial view that i'm loaded inside the dialog contains

```
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

when i'm removed it everything worked correctly